# getting attribute of <option> in<select multiple> using jquery

Tags: jquery

im using bootstrap, how can i get the attribute of  ie., gl_code_id

```
<select style="height: 400px;" multiple="" class="form-control" id="all_codes">
           <option gl_code_id="9">2345 </option>
           <option gl_code_id="8">12345 </option>
           <option gl_code_id="7">1234 </option>
           <option gl_code_id="6">90 </option>
           <option gl_code_id="5">234 </option>
           <option gl_code_id="4">1 </option>
</select>
```

tried this,

```
$(document).on("change", "#all_codes", function(){
    var id = $("#all_codes").val(); //this gives only the value
    var ids = $(this).attr('gl_code_id'); // this gives undefined
    //how can i get the selected options gl_code_id??

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#all_codes option:selected").attr('gl_code_id');
```

---

Since you're using `multiple` attribute for your `select`, if you want to retrieve all the `gl_code_id` value from multiple selected option, you can use `.map()`:

```
$(document).on("change", "#all_codes", function(){
    var id = $("#all_codes").val(); //this gives only the value
    var ids = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('gl_code_id');    
    }).get();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LFMG7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var ids = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('gl_code_id'); // return attr value

 $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // return selected option text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

you need to `.find('option:selected')`

```
var ids = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('gl_code_id');
```

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [:selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)